# Node sharp image combine without repeating

Tags: node.js, image-manipulation, sharp

I'm using node sharp image manipulation library to combine two images .One image is small and I want to add it to the top left of larger image.

This is the code I'm using

```
const output = await sharp('sea.png')
  .composite([
    { input: 'circle.png', tile: true, blend: 'over' }
  ])
  .toFile('combined.png');
```

This is the output

[Combined image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QeNU.png)

Is there a way to avoid repeating ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `tile:true` which tells sharp to repeat the image. According to documentation:

> images[].tile Boolean  set to true to repeat the overlay image across
> the entire image with the given gravity. (optional, default false)
> https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-composite#composite

So, making it like that should stop repeating

```
const output = await sharp('sea.png')
  .composite([
    { input: 'circle.png', blend: 'over' }
  ])
  .toFile('combined.png');
```